# How can I replace values of a list?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a list like this one:

```
['node.volume=Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020','node.volume2=Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020']
```

And I have the days elapsed from the date specified on my first list, and the current day, returning a list like this one.

```
[8, 8, 8]
```

How can I replace the format of the first list, with the days of the second?

To have a list like this one:

```
['node.volume=8','node.volume2=8']
```

Comment: First and third code sample aren't syntactically valid lists.

Comment: Hello @MichaelButscher I already edited the samples ;)

Comment: @jmgalan They are still not valid.

Comment: Hello @Asocia , am i missing something?

Comment: You can't put an assignment inside a list.

Comment: You're also missing quotes around the date/time strings.

Comment: @jmgalan `[node.volume=8,node.volume2=8]` copy and paste this to an interpreter. It will give you `SyntaxError` before it comes to the `NameError`

Comment: Just copy the sample in a Python shell and see what it says.

Comment: @Barmar How should I do then? I mean, How can I assign those values and then replace all?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You can make a list of strings like `["Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020", "Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020"]`

Comment: Or you can assign to the attributes first, then make a list of those values with `[node.volume, node.volume2]`

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that if you assign to `l[0]` it modifies `node.volume`, or vice versa? Neither of those is possible, you can't link different containers to each other.

Comment: jmgalan, are you still working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449261/how-can-i-join-a-string-with-his-value) issue? I still have the feeling that there should be a much easier way than all the splitting, reformatting, replacing etc.... to clarify one thing: are you on Python 2.7 or Python 3+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script like this:

```
nodevolumes=["node.volume=Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020","node.volume2=Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020", "node.volume2=Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020"]
dayselapsed=[8, 8, 8]
new_nodevolumes=[]
for i in range(len(nodevolumes)):
    vol=nodevolumes[i].split("=")
    new_nodevolumes.append(vol[0]+"="+str(dayselapsed[i]))
print(new_nodevolumes)
```

Or without using days elapsed as:

```
import datetime as datetime
nodevolumes=["node.volume=Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020","node.volume2=Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020", "node.volume2=Mon Jun 16 17:11:18 2020"]
#dayselapsed=[8, 8, 8]
new_nodevolumes=[]
for i in range(len(nodevolumes)):
    vol=nodevolumes[i].split("=")
    #new_nodevolumes.append(vol[0]+"="+str(dayselapsed[i]))
    elapsed=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime.strptime(vol[1], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
    new_nodevolumes.append(vol[0]+"="+str(elapsed.days))
print(new_nodevolumes)
```

Hope this helps.